# jQuery extend existing plugin with new option

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using slick carousel : https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

I was wondering is it possible to extend slick carousel and be able to add an option to it.

To keep things simple,  I would like to add the option border which would add a border to the carousel.

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
  border: true
});
```

Border is not part of the plugin, how would I go around to add border as an option to the slick carousel?

Thanks

Comment: Write your extension, make a pull request and wait, I guess. You could do just hack it in and use your custom version, too but then you won't be able to upgrade easily. You _might_ be able to monkeypatch it in which _might_ make upgrades easier, but it depends. For your _specific_ issue, though, you might be able to just use CSS to address it. Presumably, you need to hang it off something not all Slick enabled elements have - custom class? Unless you just want border everywhere, in which case, you don't need to bother with custom selectors.

Comment: Alright thanks, so basically this is not a viable option...Thanks

Comment: If this is a jQuery question, please add jQuery tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would do duck punching if you don't intend to mess with the original plugin, and want to add some logic of your own, provided that you are willing to actually write some codes.

```
var originalPlugin = $.fn.slick;
$.fn.slick = function(option) {
  // Execute the original plugin
  originalPlugin.call(this, option);

  if (option.border) {
    // your logic on how to apply the border
  }
}
```

That said, I don't recommend you to actually do this unless you really know what you are doing.